# How to make select without from clause using JPA

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

I need to invoke a custom SQL function in code via JPA. The function is written in pure SQL and returns relation with single boolean value.

In other words I need JPA implementation to invoke following select:

```
select function_xy(p1, p2);
```

First implementation:

```
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Boolean> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Boolean.class);
    final Expression<Boolean> func = cb.function("function_xy", Boolean.class,
            cb.literal("bla bla"), cb.literal(someEntity.getId()));
    criteriaQuery.select(func);

    final TypedQuery<Boolean> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    final List<Boolean> result = query.getResultList();
    return ResourceUtils.getSingleResult(result);
```

This throws an exception: "No criteria query roots were specified"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criteria api method "function" can not be used to invoke function in a select without a from clause.

Instead use a native query:

```
    final List<Object> result = em.createNativeQuery("select function_xy(:p1, :p2)")
            .setParameter("p1", "bla bla")
            .setParameter("p2", someEntity.getId())
            .getResultList();
    return (Boolean) ResourceUtils.getSingleResult(result);
```